# How do I subclass QApplication properly?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am a newbie with PyQt4 (and QT altogether), and am facing a problem,

I have subclassed QApplication (to have global data and functions that really are global to the application):

```
class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QApplication.__init__(self)
        self.foo = None

    def bar(self,x):
        do_something()
```

When I try to add a slot to my main window like:

`self.connect(bar, SIGNAL('triggered()'), qApp.bar)`

I get an error:
`AttributeError: bar`

What am I doing wrong? Or should I make the stuff I want global, `global stuff` instead off attributes and methods of QApplication subclass? (or something else, if so, what?)

**Note: this all worked fine when the "global" methods and attributes were in my QMainWindow -subclass...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `QtGui.qApp = self` to your `__init__` method (or try using `QApplication.instance()` instead of  `qApp`).

I hope that helps.

Comment: The former approach didn't work, `QApplication.instance()` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A pure object oriented approach is:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

....import your classes ...

'''
classes needing 'global' application attributes use for example: 
QCoreApplication.instance().mainWindow
'''

class MyApp(QApplication):

  def __init__(self, args):
    super(MyApp, self).__init__(args)
    self.mainWindow = MainWindow()  # 'global'
    ...
    self.exec_()    # enter event loop

app = MyApp(sys.argv) # instantiate app object
```

As discussed in Bertrand Meyer's "Object Oriented Software Construction", a OO program instantiates one object, the application object.  Using a `main()` procedure is a relict of C style procedural programming.

Also, the following code may crash:
In other words, `MyApp.__init__()` should enter the main event loop, not `main()`.

```
...

def main(args):
    app = MyApp(args)
    ...
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) # Qt event loop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

See other examples: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/PyQt4